# I'm trying to benchmark a C wrapper for C++ but the new operator is bogging it down?

Tags: c++, c, opencv, wrapper

This is my wrapper for Opencv's Mat::at function

```
 int &cv_Mat_at_int1(Mat* self, int i, int j) {
   return self->at<int>(i, j);
}
```

Here is how I instantiate the matrix

```
int data[] = {1,2,3,4};
Mat a = Mat(2,2,CV_8UC3, data);
```

below is the only way I know how to run the wrapper and when I run it in a loop at 1 million iterations the constant creating of the new function just eats up my ram...The equivalent C++ function, the one I'm wrapping finishes a billion iterations in 12 seconds.
Can anyone show me how to get a good idea only how much the C wrapper is adding to the C++ function and nothing else,  by not needing the new operator to test it...Thanks in advance for any advice on this.

```
cv_Mat_at_int1(new Mat (a) 0, 0);
```

Comment: What is "the equivalent C++ function"? Also, you're not creating a new function, you're creating a new object. Could you generally expand a bit more, so it would be easier to understand? Perhaps include the code you used to test?

Comment: since all you seem to want here is an additional refcount, try 'inplace new' : new (&a)Mat(a);

Comment: @berak and apparently pray `Mat` doesn't dynamically manage *anything*, since you're blasting over the top of its state with each successive call?

Comment: sorry, misread it. ignore post above.

Comment: Thank's @WhozCraig your idea worked perfect,  you should answer so I can up vote....Thanks everyone else for helping me out on this